# Parse information from external dynamically loaded js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have attached external `js` file which one changes on every visit.
this is my file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Damn</title> 
</head>
<body>
<script async="" src="//xx.example.net/checkInventory.php?_=&amp;v=3&amp;siteId=1059123&amp;minBid=0&amp;popundersPerIP=0&amp;blockedCountries=&amp;documentRef=&amp;s=1600,900,1,1600,900" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body> 
</html>
```

this is response when i type this `xx.example.net/.....` link in my browser :

```
window._pao.parse({ 'result': 1, 'url': 'http://example.com/', 'bla': 'bla', 'bla': 1 });
```

I want to simply parse this `url` in my code. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: I am confused. Please provide more info on what you have tried, and what `window._pao.parse` is?

Comment: Honestly I don't know what the hell window._pao.parse is,This is why i posted here.I tried to get this attached file with php (file_get_contents) to parse url but response is empty.

Comment: what is the line of code coming from?

Comment: Are you getting the response from this site? http://book-art-info.com/UploadFiles/2015/01/05/140751535_checkInventory.php

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Did you define `window._pao.parse`?

Comment: If you want an answer please provide good information.

Comment: Is `window._pao.parse` defined in any code you included?

Comment: @2426021684 nope not from this site it looks like that,<script async="" src="//XXXX/checkInventory.php?_=&v=3&siteId=XXX&minBid=0&popundersPerIP=0&blockedCountries=&documentRef=&s=1600,900,1,1600,900" type="text/javascript">'

Comment: @GochaKereselidze does my answer work?

Comment: @2426021684 no bro didn't work,I edit my question now and add all info i have

Comment: @GochaKereselidze did you get an error?

Comment: @2426021684 i added info to my question.Yes i got error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'parse' of undefined)

Comment: @GochaKereselidze I updated my answer, please try it again.

Comment: @GochaKereselidze try my answer again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the limited info you provided here is my best guess at what you want:

```
<script>
    window._pao = {}
    window._pao.parse = function (object){ // Declare the window._pao.parse function in order to capture  the object
        // Here object = { 'result': 1, 'url': 'http://example.com/', 'bla': 'bla', 'bla': 1 }
        // Do stuff with object here
        document.write(object.url)
    }
</script>
<script src="path/to/your/external/js/file.js"></script>
```

Comment: but this is overriding the function.

Comment: @AskingQuestions how else would you get the object?

Comment: change  `window._pao.parse` to `var window._pao.parse` and u got it. I hope

Comment: @AskingQuestions no that won't work. I think I fixed it.

Comment: @AskingQuestions Thank you too bro!!

Comment: @GochaKereselidze glade to help :)